# Turbolinks load event never firing in brand new Rails 5.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

For some reason Turbolinks is not firing the load event in my app, a brand new, recently created app.

I created a brand new Rails 5.1 app (5.1.4), using `rails new` (specifically `rails new prueba -C -d postgresql --skip-coffee --no-api`). This command automatically configures Rails to use Turbolinks, without the need of further manual configuration.

I then created a scaffold for a model (`bin/rails g scaffold Thing name`), just to have some pages to navigate to.

Finally, I created a file `app/assets/javascripts/test.js` with the following content:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks.load", function() {
  console.log("Turbolinks loaded")
});
```

After running the migration, I then run the server in development (`bin/rails s`), browse (tried both with Chrome v62 and Firefox v57), and check the developer tools console, but instead of seeing the "Turbolinks loaded" message, I get nothing:

- When I visit `/things`, the console is empty
- If I reload the same page, the console is still empty
- If I follow the "New thing" link, the console is still empty
- If, in the "New thing" page I follow the "Back" link, the console is still empty

According to the [Turbolinks README](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads):

> [...] the turbolinks:load event, which fires once on the
>   initial page load and again after every Turbolinks visit.

I was therefore expecting to see the message "Turbolinks loaded" in the console every single time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `turbolinks:load` instead of `turbolinks.load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you code you mostly missed event name. You use `turbolinks.load`, when in fact it's `turbolinks:load`. Check this url for more details -- https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads